# FindFit with Replace error

Tags: fitting, replacement

I am trying to fit my data, and I keep having error messages as below. Could anybody help me to solve this problem? The codes are written after the error messages.
[image: Error messages]

```
Oo = 3;
R = 8.314;
Wo = 15999;
Wh = 18001.8;
MW = 317127.7;
k1eqn[T_, dSox_, dHox_] = E^((-dHox + dSox (T + 273))/(R (T + 273)));
k2eqn[T_, dShyd_, dHhyd_] = E^((-dHhyd + dShyd (T + 273))/(
  R (T + 273)));
```

This [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JSJa-L-UQNzJK8LEgyOlP8psTZhzFU37ELSfLZmAbP4/edit?usp=sharing) is for the code of FullDataSet to fit. I couldn't add the dataset code as it's a lot of data. You can copy and paste the code in the link.

This is my fitting eqn. I know that I should use [[3,1,2]] or [[4,1,2]].

```
FullTestK1[ph2o_, po2_, k1_, k2_] := NSolve[Eliminate[
    k1 == (p^2*Oo)/( po2^(1/2)* vo) &&
    k2 == oh^2/(ph2o vo Oo ) &&
    delM == ((Wo*(0.1 - vo)/MW) + (Wh*oh/(2*MW)))*100 &&  
    2 vo + oh + p == 0.2,
    {p, vo, oh}], delM][[3, 1, 2]]
```

```
Fullfit = 
 FindFit[FullDataSet, {FullTestK1[ph2o, po2, k1eqn[T, dSox, dHox], 
    k2eqn[T, dShyd, 
     dHhyd]]}, {{dHox, -100000}, {dSox, -100}, {dHhyd, -100000},{dShyd, -100}}, {ph2o, po2, T}]
```

After I use FindFit, I keep having errors.

Comment: Does `Eliminate` with `[[3,1,2]]` give the desired result?  In other words, is the order of the results produced by `Eliminate` always what you want?

Answer (score 3):

To get things to work I changed the following: (1) `=` to `:=` in the definitions of `k1eqn` and `k2eqn`, (2) Added `?NumericQ` to the parameters in `FullTestK1`, (3) Changed `FindFit` to `NonlinearModelFit` so that you can find regression diagnostics and estimates of precision, and (3) scaled the parameters so that they are on approximately the same order of magnitude.

```
Oo = 3;
R = 8.314;
Wo = 15999;
Wh = 18001.8;
MW = 317127.7;
k1eqn[T_, dSox_, dHox_] := E^((-dHox + dSox (T + 273))/(R (T + 273)));
k2eqn[T_, dShyd_, dHhyd_] := 
  E^((-dHhyd + dShyd (T + 273))/(R (T + 273)));

FullTestK1[ph2o_?NumericQ, po2_?NumericQ, k1_?NumericQ, 
  k2_?NumericQ] := NSolve[Eliminate[k1 == (p^2*Oo)/(po2^(1/2)*vo) &&
  k2 == oh^2/(ph2o vo Oo) && delM == ((Wo*(0.1 - vo)/MW) + (Wh*oh/(2*MW)))*100 &&
  2 vo + oh + p == 0.2, {p, vo, oh}], delM][[3, 1, 2]]

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[FullDataSet, {FullTestK1[ph2o, po2, 
  k1eqn[T, -100 dSox, -100000 dHox], k2eqn[T, -100 dShyd, -100000 dHhyd]]},
  {{dHox, 1}, {dSox, 1}, {dHhyd, 1}, {dShyd, 1}}, {ph2o, po2, T}];
```

[image: Warning message about maybe method has stalled]

Based on the warning message, there are still issues.  A summary of the fit follows:

```
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: ParameterTable]

```
nlm["EstimatedVariance"]^0.5
(* 0.124062 *)
```

The histogram of the `"FitResiduals"` looks reasonably normal (Gaussian):

```
Histogram[nlm["FitResiduals"], "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"]
```

[image: Histogram of fit residuals]

However, the plot of residuals vs the predicted values shows a pattern suggesting an inadequacy in the proposed model:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{nlm["PredictedResponse"], nlm["FitResiduals"]}],
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Predicted response", "Residuals"}]
```

[image: Predicted response vs residuals]